# Preloading data without messing up association when data is loaded the 2nd time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is how my model looks like

```
User
belongs_to :computer

Computer
has_many :user
```

Users are created when people register for an account on the web site but computers are pre-loaded data that I create in seeds.rb/some .rake file. All is fine and good when the app is first launched and people start registering and get associated with the right computer_id. However, suppose I want to add another computer to the list

```
Computer.destroy_all
Computer.create({:name => "Akane"})
Computer.create({:name => "Yoda"})
Computer.create({:name => "Mojito"}) #newly added
```

running the rakefile the second time around will mess up the associations because computer_id in the User table refer to the old id in Computer table. Since I have run the script above, the id inside the computer table keeps incrementing without any regard to the association that user has to it. All the users now will have no reference back to its computer and all the computers now have new IDs.

Question: Is there a better way for me to pre-load data without screwing up my association? I want to be able to add new Computer without having to destroy the user's table. Destroying the computer table is fine with me and rebuilding it again but the old association that the existing users have must stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just running down the migration for the computers table?

lets say your migration's called  db/migrate/1_create_computers.rb

```
    $    rake db:migrate:down version=1
```

from the seed remove the destroy method.
You'd always keep the users table...in which by the way you must have a column computer_id

and of course the association goes

```
  ComputerClass < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users  #(don't forget the 's')
  end
```